# I Need to make more than one ajax call at a time to manage the DB

Tags: ajax

I want a "Check all" check box in a grid to let the data get updated in DB thru ajax.. but due to restriction of 2 calls at a time I am not able to make it happen. Help me to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is a little vague, but I suppose you are sending one Ajax request for each checkbox that's being checked, when the user clicks the "*check all*" button ?

If so, you should modify your code, so only **one Ajax request** is sent ; it should say the server "*oh oh, all checkboxes have been checked, do your stuff*", instead of just saying "*one checkbox has been checked*".

This way, no matter what the user does, you only have one Ajax request, which means :

- Faster
- No *(well, less)* problem with concurrency
- No problem of too many Ajax requests in parallel
- No risk of one request not making it to the server
- Less load on the server *(and the client)*

*(But, yes, I admit, it means modifying your code a little bit ;-) )*